# Finding all names in a list that contains a substring without changing the characters

Tags: python, html, django, list, search

I'm doing a key-search in a list for a search system and having a little bit of trouble in the exhibition. I found that if I lowercase both, the list with all my pages titles and the key I could do a simple search. It worked.

But in the end, to exhibit the searched titles as related results, I'm displaying the names lowercased, as I did it for comparing. I was wondering if there is any way that I could display the names as they were before comparing or a better way to do this search, looking for maintaining the original title.

This is my search function

```
def search(request):
    q = request.GET['q']
    if util.get_entry(q):
        #redirect to the existing page calling entry()
        return redirect("entry", title=q)

    #searching for matching entries titles

    #getting all the entries titles in a list
    all_entries = util.list_entries()
    #lowering case of the list and the key to avoid comparision problems
    all_entries = [item.lower() for item in all_entries]
    key = q.lower()
    #making a new list with the matching results
    match_entries = [i for i in all_entries if key in i] 

    #renders the results page passing the list of matching titles
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html",{
        'title' : q,
        'entries' : match_entries
    })
```

And this is my search page in HTML

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Search results for {{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>"{{ title }}" Search results</h1>
    <a>There is no page with the title "{{ title }}"</a>
    <ul>
       <h2>Similar results:</h2>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <a href="{% url 'entry' entry %}"><li>{{ entry }}</li></a>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? You could change the case only when doing the comparison. By the way, it's likely better to use [`str.casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) for this, rater than `str.lower()`.

Comment: Yes. I got it using the str.lower() just on the comparison but it worked with str.casefold() too, and even better I think. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided a sample of what the lists actually contain, but it should work if you only call the `.lower()` method during the check rather than making all the entries lowercase then doing the check

Rather than:

```
all_entries = [item.lower() for item in all_entries]
```

You can use

```
#proxy for your line all_entries = util.list_entries()
all_entries=['AaAaA','Baaa','cccccAAA','Dddddaa']
q='AAA'
match_entries=[i for i in all_entries if q.lower() in i.lower()]
['AaAaA', 'Baaa', 'cccccAAA']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use str like str(item).lower() that will make a new object and will change that object but not your item.

Comment: Where would that change be made? In `all_entries = [item.lower() for item in all_entries]` ?